# Unable to display the ImageView in FrameLayout in android camera

Tags: android, android-layout

As you can see in the `layout` below, I want to display both a `ImageView` and a `GLSurfaceView`. On the editor the `ImageView` is displayed within the `framelayout`, however, when I run my `camera` app , it simply displays the gl image in the `center` only, actually  I want to display the `imageView` and the `gl image` together. Why is the `ImageView` with the `id = "andme"` not `visible` in real device ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/cameraPreview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="505dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <android.opengl.GLSurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/GlViews"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="#ff2594ff" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/target"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/andme" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/background_material_dark"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mytake"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/camera" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the part of the code from within the onCreate method .
Is is causing the the only GLView image to show ? I simply want to show both the image and the glView image.

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    GLSurfaceView glSurfaceView = (GLSurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.GlViews);
    glSurfaceView.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
    // glSurfaceView.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
    glSurfaceView.setRenderer(new GLCubeRender(this,0));
    // glSurfaceView.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    glSurfaceView.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    glSurfaceView.setZOrderOnTop(true);
```

Comment: your Framelayour cameraPreview is of 505dp andme  imageview is match_parent change the width of  andme  250dp and check

Comment: Please try my answer and let me know, if any issue.

Comment: I will try it out later and let you know  Shoeb Siddique.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/cameraPreview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="550dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <android.opengl.GLSurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/GlViews"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="#ffffff" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/target"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/cream_dark"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mytake"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Sorry, I've tested your sample code but I failed. Only the GlViews is shown on the top but cannot see the android:id="@+id/target" ImageView.   I've added additional code from my MainActivity in the new edit.